# can't log on to wp-admin when wordpress is hosted as a rails subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, reverse-proxy

I have a rails app on heroku, and a wordpress-heroku install also on heroku.  I'm using the rack-reverse-proxy gem to redirect my wordpress to the /blog directory on my rails app.  I followed all the instructions here:

http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku

When I access my wordpress blog on its normal address, everything works fine.  However, when I have it set up under a subdirectory of my rails app, I can't log in.  I go to wp-login.php I enter my credentials, get forwarded to /blog/wp-admin.php, and then immediately I am redirected back to /blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1.  The only cookie that gets set is the wordpress_test_cookie, but none of the other wordpress cookies make any appearance in my browser.

I have tried many things to fix this including using rack-reverse-proxy to forward *all* rails traffic to wordpress, so I don't have to use a /blog subdirectory in case that was causing the problem.  But the exact same behavior results. I've also determined that the :preserve_host setting in the Rack::ReverseProxy config doesn't seem to make any difference whether it's true or false.

Ideas?

Comment: It looks like I'm having the same problem as this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220489/rails-heroku-app-with-wordpress-as-subfolder-unable-to-log-in-to-admin?rq=1 To clarify, I see the wordpress-test-cookie being set successfully but no other cookie is coming from wordpress when I try to log in.

Comment: did you find any answer ?

Answer (score 0):

A) What do you have in your wp-config.php? Should be something like this:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.DOMAIN.com/blog');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.DOMAIN.com/blog');
```

B) In the Rack::ReverseProxy settings, are you pointing to the blog (wordpress) herokuapp.com URL, not the main site (rails) URL, right? I realize my post isn't clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked this down to a bug in rack-reverse-proxy.  The set-cookie header was being sent in an improper format, so only the first cookie was being interpreted correctly by the browser.  That happened to be the wordpress test cookie.  All the other (useful) ones were being thrown away, so of course I could not log in.

I plan to submit a bug and branch to rack-reverse-proxy but in the meantime I fixed it with this patch in my config.ru:

```
class MyReverseProxy < Rack::ReverseProxy
  private
  def create_response_headers(http_response)
    response_headers = super(http_response)
    if response_headers
      if response_headers["Set-Cookie"].is_a?(Array)
        response_headers["Set-Cookie"] = response_headers["Set-Cookie"].join("\n")
      end
    end
    response_headers
  end
end

# this is to make /blog show my wordpress blog
use MyReverseProxy do
    reverse_proxy_options :preserve_host => false
    reverse_proxy(/^\/blog(\/.*)$/, 'http://your-blog-server.com$1')
end
```